# Files created by manage.py commands not chown'd from root user

Tags: docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I'm using cookiecutter-django project template which includes nice docker-compose integration. However when I run a manage.py command that creates a file via docker-compose e.g:

```
sudo docker-compose -f dev.yml run django python manage.py dumpdata --output ./myapp/fixtures/data.json
```

the file is owned by `root:root` so I do not initially have write permissions on my host filesystem. I'm still learning about docker-compose and am struggling to find the tidiest way to `chown` any created files back to my local user.

I did try setting the `user:` flag in my django service in dev.yml like so..

```
  django:
    user: $USER
```

but this didn't take.

I also read about using

```
django:
  user: ${UID}
```

but this also fails with a warning

```
WARNING: The UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

despite `echo $UID` returning the correct value. So for some reason, env variables are not being passed through properly, though I don't know how to go about debugging that. possibly related: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2613

edit: more updates.

so running `docker-compose -f dev.yml run django env` shows that $UID isn't present. I tried assigning it in `entrypoint.sh` but as that file is run by root, the $UID will be 0 at runtime. I'm out of ideas now as to how to pass the user ID in.

Comment: Question: Is it possible for dumpdata to output to STDOUT?  If so, just redirect the result of `docker-compose -f dev.yml run django python manage.py dumpdata > data.json` to a file on your host machine instead of saving it in the container.

Comment: This would work for dumping data like you suggest, yes. so there's that! migration files are created by the django manage.py command sadly. It's looking like there's no easy way to achieve this, and with it being an uncommon use-case a CHOWN after the files are created might have to do.